# How can I view equipped artifact details in the Heroes III iPad app?

Tags: ios, heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

I'm playing Heroes of Might and Magic 3 on the iPad app, and my hero has quite some artifacts. While I know from the PC version what for example the Ring of Infinite Gems does, I forgot the effects of some artifacts, and I also captured a spell scroll from a defeated enemy hero. How can I see the artifact details? When I tap on an artifact, a 'View [article name] info' appears in the bottom bar, but neither dragging the artifact there nor double-tapping it seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround; open the kingdom/hero overview (the castle icon in the right sidebar):

[image]

Select your heroes in the bottom right, and navigate to the right artifact section, and tap the artifact:

[image]

A popup will appear with the artifact details:

[image]